# Find the class after a clicked class in a HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive

I Have the following in my HTML:

```
             <div class="item" id="item_1">
                  Content
            </div>
             <div class="item" id="item_2">
                  Content
            </div>
             <div class="item" id="item_3">
                  Content
            </div>
              <!--CONTENT BLOCK 1-->  
             <div class="item w100" id="content_1">
                   Story
            </div>
             <!--/CONTENT BLOCK 1--> 

              <div class="item" id="item_4">
                  Content
            </div>
             <div class="item" id="item_5">
                  Content
            </div>
               <!--CONTENT BLOCK 2-->  
             <div class="item w100" id="content_2">
                   Story
            </div>
             <!--/CONTENT BLOCK 2--> 

             <div class="item" id="item_6">
                  Content
            </div>
               <!--CONTENT BLOCK 3-->  
             <div class="item w100" id="content_3">
                   Story
            </div>
             <!--/CONTENT BLOCK 3-->
```

The content blocks are hidden, only visible when an item is clicked.
I had this working fine as an unresponsive layout but now I've made the website responsive and the javascript needs to function slightly differently as each item width is different (it's a boxed grid layout).

This is the javascript:

```
        // Open Link in Content Block
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('.contentLink').click(function(event){

                var itemID=$(event.target).closest(".storyLink").attr("id");
                showBlock(itemID);
                 document.location.hash = itemID; 
                   return false;

            }); 
        });         
        function showBlock(targetID){  //load content and open dialog
             var $url = "ss_storyboard/"+targetID+".html";

            if (targetID == 'Sarah')
                {
                    loadStory("#content_1", 500, targetID);  
                }
            else if ((targetID == 'item_1') || (targetID == 'item_2') || (targetID == 'item_3'))
                {
                    loadStory("#content_2", 1700, targetID);  
                }
            else if (targetID == 'item_4'  || targetID == 'item_5')
                {
                    loadStory("#content_3", 2200, targetID);        
                }
            else if (targetID == 'item_6' || targetID == 'item_7')
                {
                    loadStory("#content_4", 2750, targetID);   
                }
            else{
                  return false;
            }
```

I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('.contentLink').click(function(event){    
                    var itemID=$(event.target).closest(".storyLink").attr("id");
                    var contentID= $(event.target).next(".w100").attr("id");
                    showBlock(itemID, contentID);
                     document.location.hash = itemID; 
                       return false;
                }); 
            });
```

But jquery's .next() only works within the content set.  Is there a way to find find the next class the comes after a clicked class in a document??

Another way I though I could do this is to detect where the line break of the items ends (ie. when the items wrap to a new line), and append the content block in dynamically after this....I'm just not sure how to go about calculating where the break would be.  All the item widths use percentages that differ for a number of media queries matching the different screen widths.

Comment: I might have missed something, but I'm not seeing `storyLink` or `contentLink`in your HTML.

Comment: Sorry,  I've added a codepen here: http://codepen.io/kirstystellar/pen/dXjPON?editors=1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Final answer**

Measure available area

```
function measureWidths(){
  var container = document.getElementById("container"),
      containerRectObject = container.getBoundingClientRect(),
      containerRight = 0;  

    containerRight = containerRectObject.right;

  return containerRight;
}
```

Go trought each storyLink and certain data-attribute if it's last of row.
This uses containerRight -value from previous function.

```
  $(".storylink").each(function(key, value) {

    $(this).append("<h2>Storylink no: " + key + "</h2>");
    $(this).attr("data-open", "false");
    $(this).attr("data-target", "content-" + key).append("<em>My data-target is 'content-" + key + "'</em>");
    storyLinkRectObject = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    storyLinkRight = storyLinkRectObject.right;

    if(storyLinkRight == containerRight){
      $(this).attr("data-row",dataRow);
      $(this).attr("data-endOfRow",dataRow);
      dataRow++;
    }else{
      $(this).attr("data-row",dataRow);
    }

  });
```

On click, dynamically move contentBlock after last storylink on the row.

```
//Destroy previous content of dynamicContentBlock
$(".dynamicContentBlock").html("");
$(".dynamicContentBlock").append(storyContent);
console.log(currentRow);
$(".dynamicContentBlock").insertAfter($("*[data-endOfRow='"+currentRow+"']"));
$(".dynamicContentBlock").show("slow");
```

Check the whole code [**HERE**](http://codepen.io/virmasalo/pen/bZxwgL?editors=0010)

---

<s>I improved my answer based on your comment. Now the code checks if window width is small or not and if it's small (mobile), it does the following.</s>

- toggle clicked `.storyLink` larger (optional)
- get wanted `.storyBlock`, based on assigned data-attributes (new)
- use `insertAfter()` -jQuery method to move selected `.storyBlock`-node
  after clicked `.storyLink` (new)
- show wanted content(your code)

**Notice:**

- I added some custom data-attributes on `.storyLink`s, `.storyblock`s
  and to `.story`-elements. (only to first set of links)
- I added `.story` for each `.storyLink` just to make things more clear to myself. Stories are now shown based on class "open".

**CodePen**
[You can find code here](http://codepen.io/virmasalo/pen/rLAbOo)

**OLD ANSWER**

<s>If I understood you right, then this might help you.</s>

Assigining data-targets (or similar), you can easily detect what content block to show on click.

I used `.toggle()` -jQuery method, but if you don't want to hide content block on second click, then you can just use `.show()` instead.

Hope this helps!

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/virmasalo/pen/wWXQwz?editors=1011)

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've added a codepen so you can see more clearly what I'm trying to achieve.  So it all works fine when it's wider screen, but when the item boxes wrap to new lines on smaller screens I want the corresponding Storyblock to be directly beneath it's item box.    http://codepen.io/kirstystellar/pen/dXjPON?editors=1111

Comment: Stellar, I'll look into that!

Comment: Thanks.  Any luck.  I had a thought of what might work but I don't know how to go about it....

Comment: This is my idea:
1. go through document and add up .item widths (might need include a counter to increment at each addition to use at step 3)
2. get windowWidth
3. if windowWidth = .itemTotalWidth then insert a div after the last addition (using the counter).             

Is this something that would be possible and work on responsive screen widths?

Comment: @Stellar, check the improved answer. Is this what you need?

Comment: Thanks for that.  But it's still doesn't work how I want it.  The main thing I'm wanting is when a contentBlock appears below an itemBox, any other itemBoxes in that row remain in that row (ie. they don't get displaced by the new content block).  The only way I can see this working now is to start off with no contentBlocks in the html, instead insert one into the html dynamically at the end of each row. I just don't know how to target the div the contentBlock needs to be inserted after.

Comment: That's why I thought calculating the widths of the divs might work, because the div that's last added to the calculation to then equal the winWidth is the div that the contentBlock needs to be inserted after to avoid disrupting any itemBoxes to another row.

Comment: @Stellar, This is how you can target the div and how to dynamically use contentBlock http://codepen.io/virmasalo/pen/bZxwgL

Comment: Thanks again.  but I need that contentBlock to be 100% on the next row.  I've been working on this the last couple of hours with no success. but I'm now thinking I could possibly use Jquerys .position() to work out the last itemBox in the row with the same top position as the clicked itemBox and then add the content block in using .after().  The content I've got to fill the contentBlocks are coming from separate html documents and loaded using .load()

Comment: @Stellar, check out the improved answer. Is this working? :D

Comment: Yeaah! Finally! Glad to help :)